# ($('#' + id).length) is not working using Jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, model-view-controller

```
$('#btnAdd').click(function () {

    var dataYear = $('#drpDataYear option:selected').text();

    var submissionType = $('#drpSubmissionType option:selected').text();

    var submissionStatus = $('#drpSubmissionStatus option:selected').text();
    var id = dataYear + submissionType + submissionStatus;

    if ((dataYear == "Year") || (submissionType == "Submission Type") 
        || (submissionStatus == "Submission Status")) {
            alert("Please select values from the drop down.");
    }
    else if ($('#' + id).length) {
        alert("Value already exists");
    }
    else {
        var markup = "<tr id = " + id + " ><td class='dataYearField'>" + dataYear 
            + "</td><td class='submissionType'>" + submissionType 
            + "</td><td class='submissionStatus'>" + submissionStatus 
            + "</td> <td>  <input type=button id='btnDel' name='btnDel' value='Delete' class='btn btn-danger'/></td></tr>";
        $("table tbody").append(markup);
    }
});
```

In the above code  `($('#' + id).length)` does not work at times.Could someone suggest a better way to find duplicate and show alert?

Comment: What is the value in `var id` ?

Comment: var id = dataYear + submissionType + submissionStatus;

Comment: all these fields have static values.

Comment: I'm asking about the actual value you got in `var id` after concat those 3 variables into that.

Comment: it will be like '2017NCNNo'

Comment: "... does not work at times" - so when it doesn't work, what are the symptoms?

Comment: Check if `$("table tbody").find('#' + id).length` works!

Comment: do your values that represent your id contain something that might not be acceptible for use in ID strings?

Comment: @PrashantShirke - the code is not working.. It adds already existing values

Comment: ID-s are not supposed to start with a digit - they must contain only `\w` (word) characters and must start with a letter.

Comment: have you tried `$('#drpDataYear').val()` instead of `$('#drpDataYear option:selected').text()`? I think this is the mistake. If the variables before have nothing, then the following selector wouldn't match.

Comment: Compose the id string in a different order, Instead of `var id = dataYear + submissionType + submissionStatus;`, try `var id = submissionType + submissionStatus + dataYear;`

Answer (score 0):

I would do a search for the element and assign it to a variable and then do a check on the length of that variable.

```js
$('#btnAdd').click(function () {

    var dataYear = $('#drpDataYear option:selected').text();

    var submissionType = $('#drpSubmissionType option:selected').text();

    var submissionStatus = $('#drpSubmissionStatus option:selected').text();
    var id = dataYear + submissionType + submissionStatus;
    var idCount = $('#' + id);

    if ((dataYear == "Year") || (submissionType == "Submission Type") 
        || (submissionStatus == "Submission Status")) {
            alert("Please select values from the drop down.");
    }
    else if (idCount.length >= 1) {
        alert("Value already exists");
    }
    else {
        var markup = "<tr id = " + id + " ><td class='dataYearField'>" + dataYear 
            + "</td><td class='submissionType'>" + submissionType 
            + "</td><td class='submissionStatus'>" + submissionStatus 
            + "</td> <td>  <input type=button id='btnDel' name='btnDel' value='Delete' class='btn btn-danger'/></td></tr>";
        $("table tbody").append(markup);
    }
});
```

Comment: This works first time. But the second when i keep on adding the same elemet to the grid , the alert doesnot work

Comment: Then look at your browser console if it blocks the second execution due to obsolete user experience.

Answer (score 0):

This is because jQuery is not able to find the newly added element in the DOM. I'd be using Craig's answer and would add my solution to it below:

```js
$('#btnAdd').click(function () {

    var dataYear = $('#drpDataYear option:selected').text();

    var submissionType = $('#drpSubmissionType option:selected').text();

    var submissionStatus = $('#drpSubmissionStatus option:selected').text();
    var id = dataYear + submissionType + submissionStatus;
    var idCount = $(document.getElementById(id)); // This may sound weird but it works
    // Or you can also do it this way but i have not tested this one
    // var idCount = $('div#parent').find('#' + id);

    if ((dataYear == "Year") || (submissionType == "Submission Type") 
        || (submissionStatus == "Submission Status")) {
            alert("Please select values from the drop down.");
    }
    else if (idCount.length >= 1) {
        alert("Value already exists");
    }
    else {
        var markup = "<tr id = " + id + " ><td class='dataYearField'>" + dataYear 
            + "</td><td class='submissionType'>" + submissionType 
            + "</td><td class='submissionStatus'>" + submissionStatus 
            + "</td> <td>  <input type=button id='btnDel' name='btnDel' value='Delete' class='btn btn-danger'/></td></tr>";
        $("table tbody").append(markup);
    }
});
```

I hope this works out for you